# bag of featuresにおけるエラー

Tags: opencv, python3, jupyter-notebook

正解ラベル作成

```py
labels=np.append(["dolphin"]*len(list(images["dolphin"])),["elephant"]*len(list(images["elephant"])))
```

<sup>(このソースコードは、[アルフ](http://alfredplpl.hatenablog.com/about)さんの記事[「Bag-of-Featuresの実装」](http://alfredplpl.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/10/17/171048)中にある [bofTest.py](https://gist.github.com/alfredplpl/7020937) を参考にしています。)</sup>

エラーコード

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

入力画像に対して、正解ラベルを作成の際に上記のようなエラーが出ました。どうやってエラーを回避すればよいのでしょうか、お教えいただければ幸いです。

#### 追記

`type(images["dolphin"])`の結果は `class map` となりました。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらのソースコードには、何か出典がありますか？　それともご自身で書かれたコードでしょうか。前者であれば、適切に引用して頂きたいです。

Comment: すいません。引用もとは、https://gist.github.com/alfredplpl/7020937　こちらです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。自分の質問は「編集」から自由に追記できますので、質問文に書き足して頂けますでしょうか。（コメントは後から来た方からは読みにくいためです。）

Comment: `type(images["dolphin"])` の結果を教えて頂けますか？

Comment: type(images["dolphin"])の結果は class map となりました。

Comment: このエラーは、本当にこの行から直接発生していますか？　Python 3 の `map` はイテレーターであるため、それぞれの要素は、`list(images["dolphin"])` など、それを参照しようとしたときに初めて評価が起きます。[参考になさったコード](https://gist.github.com/alfredplpl/7020937)はおそらく Python 2 + OpenCV 2 を対象としており、そのままでは Python 3 で動かすことができないため、幾らかコードを変更していらっしゃると思います。そのあたりで何か原因になりそうなコードはありませんか？　なお、少なくとも Python 2.7 + OpenCV 2.4.11 で引用元のコードが上手く動くことは確認いたしました。

Comment: （というのも、Python 3 において map から list への変換はできるはずで、list にはlen() があり、 list * 数 も定義でき、それらに対する np.append も可能であるはずだからです。）

Comment: おっしゃる通りだと思います。自分で修正した箇所に間違いがないか、見てみます。ご指摘ありがとうございました。

Comment: もし原因が見つかれば、是非[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)をお願いします。もちろん、なかなか見つからなければこの質問に追記するか、新しい質問を投稿して頂いても結構です。よろしくお願いいたします :)